# How to fix the animation?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

*The blue block collapses and unfolds, and I need it to appear and perform an animation where it slides down
It's all about slideToggle(300) - this is the very animation of folding and unfolding. I don't want to change the code too much, what can I do about it?*
**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>JS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylet.css">
    <script src="javat.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" class="content_toggles"\>
    <input type="button" class="content_blocks"\>
</body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
body {
    background-color: gray;
}

.content_toggles {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-image: url("img/builderhall1.png");
    background-size: 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.content_blocks {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.content_toggles').click(function(){
    $('.content_blocks').slideToggle(300);
      document.getElementById("content_blocks").style.display = "block";
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you're asking here - you should clarify by writing what the issue you're facing is, and what the expected result should be. However, I did notice that you're including your JS file before you load the jQuery library. Simply swap the order of these two lines, or else your javascript code won't work. This is because your javascript code uses jQuery, but you are loading your code before you initialize the jQuery library. Change your HTML to look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>JS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylet.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javat.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" class="content_toggles"\>
    <input type="button" class="content_blocks"\>
</body>
</html>
```

I also noticed you are trying to access the `content_blocks` element by its ID, but you define it by class. Instead of `document.getElementById("content_blocks").style.display = "block";` do

```js
// vanilla JS
document.querySelector(".content_blocks").style.display = "block";

// jQuery
$('.content_blocks').style.display = "block";
```

Or you can do

```html
<input type="button" id="content_toggles"\>
<input type="button" id="content_blocks"\>
```

Comment: Nice catch... So I rolled back my edit on OP's question ;)

Comment: I would recommend to use querySelector instead of `getElementsByClassName` and taking a whole HTML Collection. Alternativly you simply could use the jquery equivalent `$('.content_blocks')`

Comment: @tacoshy good point. `querySelector` is probably better, and the jQuery equivalent is probably best. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.content_toggles').click(function(){
    $('.content_blocks').slideToggle(300);
      
});
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: gray;
}

.content_toggles {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-image: url("img/builderhall1.png");
    background-size: 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.content_blocks {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>JS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylet.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="javat.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" class="content_toggles"\>
    <input type="button" class="content_blocks"\>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The blue block is collapsing anyway. It should just appear and move down, not unfold and collapse

Comment: so you mean it should appear then slidedown but yellow are still there? is that the one you want? let me know.